# gnuplottex and lualatex

Tags: luatex, gnuplot, shell-escape

**EDIT:** This question covers a bug in [`gnuplottex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex) which will be fixed in TeXLive 2013.If you still want to have the bug fixed, download the latest upstream version from CTAN and compile it yourself.

---

Let `gnu.tex`

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{gnuplottex} % use gnuplot
\usepackage{epstopdf} % convert resulting eps to pdf
\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
    set xlabel '$x$'
    set ylabel '$y$'
    plot sin(x) title '$\sin x$'
\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

I am now trying to compile with `lualatex`; unfortuantely this doesn't work. I called `lualatex` in the manner

```
$ lualatex --shell-escape gnu.tex
```

The log file reads

```
...
 \write18 enabled.
...
Package gnuplottex Warning: Shell escape not enabled.
(gnuplottex)                You'll need to convert the graphs yourself..
...
```

If I compile with `pdflatex` and the command line

```
$ pdflatex --shell-escape gnu.tex
```

it works just fine.

**Summary:** Is `gnuplottex` incompatible with `lualatex`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd consider this a bug in `gnuplottex.sty`: the package tests shell escape by writing a file in `/tmp` and assigning it a name *without* extension. TeX implementations may differ in the treatment of missing extensions in file names, but should do the same thing when an extension is found. So if the test is

```
%% test if shell escape really works
\ifShellEscape
  \def\tmpfile{/tmp/w18-test-\the\year\the\month\the\day\the\time.tex}
  \ifmiktex
    \def\tmpfile{w18-test-\the\year\the\month\the\day\the\time.tex}
    \immediate\write18{echo t > "\tmpfile"}
  \else
    \immediate\write18{touch \tmpfile}
  \fi
  \IfFileExists{\tmpfile}{\ShellEscapetrue}{\ShellEscapefalse}
  \ifmiktex
    \immediate\write18{del "\tmpfile"}
  \else
    \immediate\write18{rm -f \tmpfile}
  \fi
\fi
```

all will work (I've added an explicit `.tex` extension).

You can work around this bug by adding your own test:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{gnuplottex} % use gnuplot
\usepackage{pdftexcmds,ifluatex}
\makeatletter
\ifluatex
  \ifnum\pdf@shellescape=\@ne
    \ShellEscapetrue
  \fi
\fi
\makeatother

\usepackage{epstopdf} % convert resulting eps to pdf
\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
    set xlabel '$x$'
    set ylabel '$y$'
    plot sin(x) title '$\sin x$'
\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

You'll still get the message, but the document will compile correctly when `-shell-escape` is given in the command line. You need LuaTeX version >0.67 for this workaround, though.

Comment: What a great and helpful answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've e-mailed the developer this bug fix. Is it possible to get this fix back to TeXLive 2012, which is frozen since a week?

Comment: No, as `tlmgr` says: TeX Live 2012 is **frozen forever** and will no longer be updated. But you could take the updated package and put it in the same folder as your *main* tex-file (meaning the one where you are writing you thesis, paper, etc.). To myself: I haven't known `gnuplottex`, but I think it might be to slow if you have many or complicated graphics. Maybe you would like to let `gnuplot` run beside `(lua/pdf)latex` and include the eps- oder converted pdf-files that are generated? Will give you a real speed-up if you have more than lets say...ten plots?

Comment: @DL6ER Thank you for your answer, although it's a pity that you cannot backport fixes. Regarding the speed issue: You're right, but normally I don't have more than 3 plots and if I'm writing a paper I have to split them off as all the journals only accept separate plots.